# Group data by day to zoo times series object in R.

Tags: r

i read a csv file and save it in a zoo time series object. 
This file contains intradaily measures(every 15 minutes)  for 9 parameters from photovoltaic modules. 
i want to separate the data (make them group) for each day in order to call the functions that i have made to run for each day's measurements.
my code is :

```
data1<-read.zoo("C:/Users/Christiana/Desktop/excelfile/data1.csv",format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep=',', tz = "Etc/GMT+2", skip=1, dec=".")
colnames(data1)<-c('vdc','idc','pdc', 'pac', 'tmod', 'edc', 'eac', 'gpyrano', 'gcsi', 'sw', 'aw', 'tamb', 'rh','gh')
 data1<-na.omit(data1)
GH <- c(coredata(data1$gh)[1], coredata(data1$gh)[1:nrow(data1)-1])

data1<-cbind(data1,GH)
z<-index(data1)
   source('models.R')
```

models.R:

```
solarf<-cbind(G0=data$GH,Ta=data$tamb)
Gef<-calcGef(latitude, modeTrk='fixed', modeRad='bdI',dataRad=solarf,keep.night=TRUE, beta=title_pv, alfa=azimuth, iS=degree_of_dirtiness, alb=reflection, horizBright=TRUE, HCPV=FALSE)
model_G_cal<-cbind(Bn=Gef@GefI$Bn,Gsim=Gef@GefI$G,B=Gef@GefI$B,D=Gef@GefI$D,Di=Gef@GefI$Di,Dc=Gef@GefI$Dc,R=Gef@GefI$R,GH=data$GH,Gcsi=data$gcsi)

Gi<-val_Gi(model_G_cal$Gcsi,model_G_cal$Gsim)

Tmod_sim_Gcsi<-cbind(Tmod_sim=Tmodpred(data$tmod,data$tamb,data$gcsi,data$sw,data$aw,data$rh),Tmod_meas=data$tmod)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

zoo provides a `split` method so if `z` is a zoo object then:

```
L <- split(z, as.Date(time(z)))
```

creates a list whose components are the parts of the zoo object for each date.

Next time please cut down the code you show to its essentials and also make it reproducible which means all input must be provided.